# Node / MongoDB - If no User exist auto creat admin user

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've the schema below and i want to creat automatically a default user(admin) when there is no user at all.

For example:

name: Carl
email: name@test.com
password: qwertz123
role: 1

userModel:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Vorname'],
      trim: true,
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Email'],
      trim: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Passwort'],
    },
    role: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0, // 0 = user, 1 = Admin,
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a term known as migration. You should create a migration that creates an admin user.